# How to do git clone --bare using repo tool?

Tags: git, repo

I am looking for a option in repo tool XML file to do "git clone --bare". By default repo tool is cloning the entire git repository. Can anyone tell me how can I do bare clone using repo tool?

Comment: It's unclear what a bare clone would mean in the kind of multi-repository scenario that `repo` is designed for.

Comment: Add `--mirror` to `repo init`. The bare repositories exist in `.repo/projects` without `--mirror`.